# How to override a JS variable in Odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Consider the below class exists

```
local.MyWidget = instance.Widget.extend({
    events: {
        "click .my_button": "button_clicked",
    },
    button_clicked: function() {
        console.log("Button Clicked");
    }
});
```

I want to add one more event to the variable like below

```
MyWidget.include({
    events: {
        "click .new_button": "new_button_clicked",
    },

    new_button_clicked: function() {
        console.log("New Button Clicked.");
    }
});
```

The above doesn't work and the error i get is

> events is undefined

How this can be done in odoo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this as well:

```
MyWidget.include({
    init: function(parent, options) {
        this.events["click .new_button"] = "new_button_clicked";
        this._super(parent, options);
    },

    new_button_clicked: function() {
        console.log("New Button Clicked.");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, this.events needs to be initialized before calling this.super method for the changes to take effect. I've edited your answer, pls approve it and i'll mark the answer as right.

Comment: Approved. Thanks for the feedback Vivek.

Comment: @Vivek Why do i get this.events is undefined with this?
note: I'm using ListView.include({..})

Comment: @mkchx events may not be defined in ListView. Kindly check if it exists.